# Find $A^5-4A^4+7A^3+11A^2-A-10I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation

> If$$A=  \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & 4   \\
>     2 & 3
>   \end{bmatrix},$$then find $A^5-4A^4+7A^3+11A^2-A-10I$ where $I$ is Identity matrix of $2^{nd}$ order. 
>   Answer should come in terms of $A$ and $I$.

My approach: I thought it would might end up in a pattern so I found

$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}    9 & 16   \\    8 & 17  \end{bmatrix}$$
and similarly $A^3$ but got no such pattern. I don't want to evaluate it to up to $A^5$. Any better approach or solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Idea: consider the matrix
$$
A(t) =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
t & 2(t+1) \\
t+1 & 2(t+1) - 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: Did you try diagonalising it?

Comment: Duplicate of [Calculate $A^5 - 27A^3 + 65A^2$ for $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 \\ -2&1&4\end{bmatrix}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909758/calculate-a5-27a3-65a2-for-a-beginbmatrix-0-0-1-3-1-0).  Same method(s), different parameters.

Comment: Alternatively, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110899/cayley-hamilton-on-2-times-2-matrix-to-express-5-degree-polynomial) has almost the same polynomial. Any chance you got the sign of the $A^3$ coefficient wrong?

Comment: The highlighted question tells you to “Compute ... by Cayley-Hamilton.” That’s the better approach that you’re asking for. Painstakingly computing powers of the matrix and hoping to find a pattern, as you’ve tried, is not that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the eigenvalues of $A$ are $5$ and $-1$ you have $A^2 -4A - 5I = 0_{2\times2}$

Polynomial division gives:

- $A^5-4A^4+7A^3+11A^2-A-10I = (A^3+12A+59I)(A^2-4A-5I)+295A + 285I$

So, the result is
$$\boxed{295A + 285I}$$

Answer (score 4):

The characteristic polynomial of that matrix is $\lambda^2-4\lambda-5$. So, by the Hamilton-Cayley theorem, $A^2-4A-5\operatorname{Id}=0$. In other words, $A^2=4A+5\operatorname{Id}$. Can you take it from here?